# Upload large files as a stream to s3 with Plain Javascript using AWS-SDK-JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

There is a pretty [nice example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-the-amazon-s3-managed-uploader-in-the-aws-sdk-for-javascript/) available for uploading large files to s3 via aws-sdk-js library but unfortunately this is using nodeJs fs.

Is there a way we can achieve the same thing in Plain Javascript? Here is a nice [Gist](https://gist.github.com/alediaferia/cfb3a7503039f9278381) as well which breaks down the large file into the smaller Chunks however this is still missing the .pipe functionality of nodeJs fs which is required to pass to asw-sdk-js upload function. Here is a relevant code snippet as well in Node.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var zlib = require('zlib');

var body = fs.createReadStream('bigfile').pipe(zlib.createGzip());
var s3obj = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: 'myKey'}});
s3obj.upload({Body: body}).
  on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) {
    console.log('Progress:', evt.loaded, '/', evt.total); 
  }).
  send(function(err, data) { console.log(err, data) });
```

Is there something similar available in Plain JS (non nodeJs)? Useable with Rails.

Specifically, an alternative to the following line in Plain JS.

```
var body = fs.createReadStream('bigfile').pipe(zlib.createGzip());
```

Comment: this type of problem is solved by asking the client to send you the file (email, ftp, pendrive, etc), and you upload it using the aws command line, such a large upload usually only occurs once in the client's lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

The same [link you provided](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-the-amazon-s3-managed-uploader-in-the-aws-sdk-for-javascript/) contains an implementation intended for the Browser, and it also uses the [AWS client SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property).

```
// Get our File object
var file = $('#file-chooser')[0].files[0];

// Upload the File
var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'myBucket'});
var params = {Key: file.name, ContentType: file.type, Body: file};
bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
  $('#results').html(err ? 'ERROR!' : 'UPLOADED.');
});
```

** EDITS **

Note the documentation for the `Body` field includes `Blob`, which means streaming will occur:

> Body — (Buffer, Typed Array, Blob, String, ReadableStream)

You can also use the Event Emitter convention in the client offered by the AWS SDK's [ManagedUpload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html) interface if you care to monitor [progress](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html#httpUploadProgress-event). Here is an example:

```
var managed = bucket.upload(params)
managed.on('httpUploadProgress', function (bytes) {
  console.log('progress', bytes.total)
})
managed.send(function (err, data) {
  $('#results').html(err ? 'ERROR!' : 'UPLOADED.');
})
```

If you want to read the file from your local system in chunks before you send to [s3.uploadPart](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#uploadPart-property), you'll want to do something with [Blob.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/slice), perhaps defining a [Pipe Chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Concepts#Pipe_chains).

Comment: the question is about uploading a file as a stream

Comment: @fgeorgiew ok, the challenge is to make `Body` conform to the "stream" interface.

Comment: @fgeorgiew actually, passing the file object will cause streaming. if you want to monitor the progress of the transfer, avoid the callback convention and prefer the event emitter convention.